# (Steam) Mount ext4 partition with exec permissions

Tags: partitioning, permissions, steam

I have most of my disk space in an `ext4` partition which I automountt on startup through `fstab`. The corresponding line in `fstab`is this one:

```
/dev/sda9 /media/rest    ext4  users,user    0  0
```

Now I'm trying to install a game through `Steam` and I want the data folder to be stored in said partition, but when I try to select a folder in it I get the error:

```
New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions
```

So I need that partition to have *execute permissions*. I'm guessing modifying the line in `fstab` to this might do the trick:

```
/dev/sda9 /media/rest    ext4  users,user,exec    0  0
```

but I'm not really sure and I don't want to mess up my system. Is this the correct solution for the mentioned issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `defaults` option in fstab will give you what you want. As per `mount` ,

`man mount`

```
defaults
          Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

So a line like

```
/dev/sda9 /media/rest    ext4  defaults    0  0
```

should be OK.

Comment: `defaults` didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04. any idea?

Comment: check FLC I have just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `defaults` but later you use `users`, it comes with its own set of options.

From `man mount`:

```
users
  Allow any user to mount and to unmount the filesystem, even when some other ordinary user mounted it. This  option  implies  the  options noexec, nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line users,exec,dev,suid).
```

So a proper line to have exec permissions and allow users to mount/umount would be:

```
/dev/sda9 /media/rest    ext4  defaults,users,exec    0  0
```

There's no need to use `users` and `user`, the first one covers the second.