# How to add execute permissions to a USB Flash Drive ext4 (for steam)

Tags: partitioning, usb, permissions, steam, usb-drive

How to add execute permissions to a USB Flash Drive ext4 (for steam)

This is what I think I need to do [(Steam) Mount ext4 partition with exec permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316440/steam-mount-ext4-partition-with-exec-permissions), but I am not sure how to add the exec to the mount permissions, as the USB drive currently has the noexec permission, I'm wondering how to change this so I can use it for steam. (I hope this makes sense)

Update: Here's the relevant line from the `mount` output:

```
/dev/sda2 on /var/host/media/removable/James type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,dirsync,data=ordered)
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `mount | grep '/dev/sdX'` with your USB drive mounted, where `/dev/sdX` is its device file descriptor (you can check which one it is with the output of `lsblk`).

Comment: /dev/sda2 on /var/host/media/removable/James type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,dirsync,data=ordered) this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remount a device with `exec` option (the opposite of `noexec`) using this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /PATH/TO/MOUNTPOINT
```

Just replace `/PATH/TO/MOUNTPOINT` with the correct mount point, so in your case it would be:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /var/host/media/removable/James
```

After that, check the output of `mount | grep '/dev/sda2` again to make sure the `noexec` option is gone. There will probably not be any `exec` option listed though, because that's the default.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the gry check button on its left. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: worked, almost but unplugging the drive caused it to revert

Comment: Yeah, this command remounts it with different options only once. To make that persistent, you would have to add a rule in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: ok, I think I found a resouce to help me do that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#ext2_and_ext3

Comment: @ByteCommander, I have tried this command using the mount point path of `/dev/sdb1` and `/media/vass/788A-12B` and `/media/resort/` without success. (ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. after the command trying chmod 777 on the binary file to make it executable fails to change anything.